# How to change the content in specified GridView element with index number

Tags: gridview, qml, qtquick2, listmodel

i am building a project's front-end side with QtQuick2. I am having a trouble with popup styled elements. I created a ListElement first, then created a GridView and put ListElement elements into that by using model. That is a 3x3 grid and what i am trying to do is when user clicked on an element, i want the change background image of that element.

default state

[image: default state]

expected state

[image: expected state]

It happens but it stays under the other elements of grid. I tried to set visibility of element which stays upper on z-index but i was not able to reach grid[index]'s properties. Here is what happens

my build

[image: tested version of state]

Here is my code

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item {

Text {
    id: textDevice
    x: 312
    y: 69
    text: "CİHAZ AYARLARI"
    color: "#4A4A4A"
    font.pixelSize: 22
    font.weight: 400
    font.family: "SF Pro Text"
}


ListModel {
    id: deviceSettings
    ListElement { name: "DİL SEÇİMİ";  src:"/images/deviceSettingsRect.png"; status:"disabled" }
    ListElement { name: "WIFI AYARLARI";  src:"/images/deviceSettingsRect.png" }
    ListElement { name: "GÜÇ KORUMASI";  src:"/images/deviceSettingsRect.png" }
    ListElement { name: "TARİH AYARI"; src:"/images/deviceSettingsRect.png" }
    ListElement { name: "KAYIT PERİYODU"; src:"/images/deviceSettingsRect.png" }
    ListElement { name: "E-POSTA AYARLARI";  src:"/images/deviceSettingsRect.png"}
    ListElement { name: "SAAT AYARI";  src:"/images/deviceSettingsRect.png" }
    ListElement { name: "RAKIM"; src:"/images/deviceSettingsRect.png" }
    ListElement { name: "SMS AYARLARI";  src:"/images/deviceSettingsRect.png" }
}


GridView {
    id: deviceGrid
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.leftMargin: 104
    anchors.topMargin: 152
    model: deviceSettings
    cellHeight: 75
    cellWidth: 205
    delegate: Rectangle {
        id: deviceRects
        width: 182
        height: 68
        color: "transparent"
        z: 900

        Text{
            color: "#4A4A4A"
            text: name
            font.family: "SF Pro Text"
            font.weight: 400
            font.pixelSize: 14
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.top: parent.top
            anchors.topMargin: 25
            z: 999
        }

        Image {
            id: deviceBackground
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: src
        }

        MouseArea{
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                deviceGrid.currentIndex = index;

                if(name==="DİL SEÇİMİ"){
                    if(status==="enabled"){
                        deviceRects.width = 182
                        deviceRects.height = 143
                        deviceBackground.source = "/images/langSelect.png"
                        console.log(index)
                        status="disabled"
                    }else{
                        deviceRects.width = 182
                        deviceRects.height = 68
                        deviceBackground.source = "/images/deviceSettingsRect.png"
                        status="enabled"
                    }
                }else if(name==="WIFI AYARLARI"){
                    if(status==="enabled"){
                        deviceRects.width = 182
                        deviceRects.height = 143
                        deviceBackground.source = "/images/langSelect.png"
                        console.log(index)
                        status="disabled"
                    }else{
                        deviceRects.width = 182
                        deviceRects.height = 68
                        deviceBackground.source = "/images/deviceSettingsRect.png"
                        status="enabled"
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        }


    }


}
```

I reviewed this [How to access the property of a GridView - or ListView - element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131316/how-to-access-the-property-of-a-gridview-or-listview-element) but still wasn't able to figure it out. Any suggestions? If i can reach the index number of 2nd row 1st column, i would hide it by visibility property but i could not.

Extra quick question(later edit)
I want to create a timer setter in one of these pop-ups. When user click they should see this inside 3rd row 1st column.

[image]

I've created a timer which takes the current time from computer. I want user to be able to change it by this pop-up. Here is my timer

```
Timer{
    interval : 500
    running : true
    repeat : true

    onTriggered: {
        var date = new Date()
        clockText.text = date.toLocaleTimeString(Qt.locale("en_US"), "hh:mm")
    }
}
```

I can use up/down arrows or something else instead of upper or lower number previews but how can i set it in ListElement and save as original value. I checked on

[Time input field in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46243460/time-input-field-in-qml)

[Time Picker in QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29273544/time-picker-in-qml)

[How to add Date and Time picker in qt qml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221447/how-to-add-date-and-time-picker-in-qt-qml)

Comment: I wouldn't store it in a `ListElement`. Those are for similar data items like your "buttons" all have a name and a src property, perfect for `ListElements`, but if single element has a timer value this would mean all the other don't and you need to create a lot of branching in the delegate, because you need to distinguish between the one with timer and the others. There is something called the `DelegateModel` in QML with which you can create groups, but again a group should contain more than one item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't increase the size of the elements inside the cells, but use a popup which opens on top. I've changed your code in order for it to work as expected without using the images, because they are not available to us. Have a look at how the `z` property of the `Rectangle` is used when its `height` gets increased. I set it to `1` when it is active and set it back to `0` if not.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    id: root
    width: 1024
    height: 768
    visible: true
    color: "#aaddff"

    ListModel {
        id: deviceSettings
        ListElement { name: "DİL SEÇİMİ" }
        ListElement { name: "WIFI AYARLARI" }
        ListElement { name: "GÜÇ KORUMASI" }
        ListElement { name: "TARİH AYARI" }
        ListElement { name: "KAYIT PERİYODU" }
        ListElement { name: "E-POSTA AYARLARI" }
        ListElement { name: "SAAT AYARI" }
        ListElement { name: "RAKIM" }
        ListElement { name: "SMS AYARLARI" }
    }

    GridView {
        id: deviceGrid
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.leftMargin: 104
        anchors.topMargin: 152
        model: deviceSettings
        cellHeight: 75
        cellWidth: 205
        currentIndex: -1

        delegate: Rectangle {
            id: deviceRects
            width: 182
            height: 68
            gradient: Gradient {
                GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "#f7f9f9" }
                GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "#c5dcec" }
            }
            radius: 20
            border.color: mouseArea.containsMouse ? "gray" : "#ffffff"
            border.width: 2

            Text {
                color: "#4A4A4A"
                text: name
                font.family: "SF Pro Text"
                font.weight: 400
                font.pixelSize: 14
                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
                anchors.top: parent.top
                anchors.topMargin: 25
            }

            states: [
                State {
                    name: "default"
                    when: deviceGrid.currentIndex !== index
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: deviceRects
                        height: 68
                        z: 0
                    }
                },
                State {
                    name: "active"
                    when: deviceGrid.currentIndex === index
                    PropertyChanges {
                        target: deviceRects
                        height: 143
                        z: 1
                    }
                }
            ]

            MouseArea {
                id: mouseArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                hoverEnabled: true
                onClicked: {
                    if (deviceGrid.currentIndex === index)
                        deviceGrid.currentIndex = -1
                    else
                        deviceGrid.currentIndex = index
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh it makes sense.. That was exactly what i was trying to do. Now i replaced gradients with my original images and it works like a charm. I have another quick question but i don't want to create a new question for that. I will add that in my current one, if you can take a look at that i would be appreciated. And Peter, you are blessed.

Comment: Nice use of states.